# format DateTime in xsl (1.0) when Month/Date can only be one digit long

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to format the following given datetime

> 2013-3-4 12:57:49

to

> 20130304

actually im using this xsl code

```
<xsl:variable name="OrderDate"><xsl:value-of select="Belegexport/Beleg/Kopf/Header_Datum" /></xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($OrderDate, 1, 4),substring($OrderDate, 6, 1),substring($OrderDate, 8, 1))"/>
```

The result is

> 201334

.

but i need Zeros's when Month or date are 1 digit long and no Zero's when Month or Date are 2 digits long.

How could i handle this? 
I cant change the `Datasource` and i'm bound to xslt version 1.0.

any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
<xsl:variable name="year" select="substring($OrderDate, 1, 4)" />
<xsl:variable name="afterYear" select="substring($OrderDate, 6)" />
<xsl:variable name="month" select="substring-before($afterYear, '-')" />
<xsl:variable name="day" select="substring(substring-after($afterYear, '-'), 1, 2)" />
<xsl:value-of select="$year * 10000 + $month * 100 + $day" />
```